# How to securely handle user input in airline management system and store in database? Need help identifying and resolving issue

Tags: security

I'm a software engineer working on our airline management system. I need to get user input and store it in our database, but I'm not sure what would be the best way. Our code is in Python, and here is how we interact with our database and user:

```
# Initializing the airline management system
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('airplanes.db', password='D*#g6kY9F$B5')

# Create cursor object to execute SQL statements
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Execute SQL queries

# Create a table
create_table_query = '''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS airplanes (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        airplaneName TEXT,
    )
'''
cursor.execute(create_table_query)

# Insert data into the table
insert_data_query = '''
    INSERT INTO airplanes (name, age, department)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
'''
airplane_data = ( '723423', 'Starlight')
cursor.execute(insert_data_query, airplane_data)

# Fetch data from the table
select_data_query = '''
    SELECT * FROM airplanes
'''
cursor.execute(select_data_query)
result = cursor.fetchall()

# Print the fetched data
for row in result:
    print(row)

# Commit the changes and close the connection
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I want to sanitize input since I love being secure! Just having a hard time with this one. Thanks!